# Android Studio is automatically adding slashes to string that I don't want

Tags: android, string

I have the following string:

> \uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC40\uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC40\uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC40\uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC40\uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC40 good **** go౦ԁ ****\uD83D\uDC4C thats \u2714 some good\uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC4C****right\uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC4Cthere\uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC4C right\u2714there \u2714\u2714if i do ƽaү so my self \uD83D\uDCAF i say so \uD83D\uDCAF thats what im talking about right there right there (chorus: ʳᶦᵍʰᵗ ᵗʰᵉʳᵉ) mMMMM\u13B7М\uD83D\uDCAF \uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC4C \uD83D\uDC4CНO0ОଠOOOOOОଠଠOooo\u1D52\u1D52\u1D52\u1D52\u1D52\u1D52\u1D52\u1D52\u1D52\uD83D\uDC4C \uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC4C \uD83D\uDC4C \uD83D\uDCAF \uD83D\uDC4C \uD83D\uDC40 \uD83D\uDC40 \uD83D\uDC40 \uD83D\uDC4C\uD83D\uDC4CGood sh

(The **** replace some swear words).

I want to be able to use this string in my code. The problem is that when I paste this string into my program like this:

```
String s = "<THE STRING>"
```

Android Studio automatically adds a slash before every slash. This prevents any of the characters from loading into their respective emojjis and instead leaves them as their literal value.

How can I prevent Android Studio from automatically adding slashes when I paste a string into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paste it in using the key commands `ctrl + alt + shift + v`